# how to rewrite url in Yii?

Tags: php, yii, url-routing

I have an action named contact in the site controller, so when I open it in the browser, the url displayed as: `mysite.com/index.php/site/contact`, I want to change it to be just the view name of the action, so it should be `mysite.com/contact.php`, how to do that ?

Comment: set cursor on url -> select part of url -> write new url -> that how you can rewrite url :) sorry for that, just joke

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the index.php from the url you'll need to add `'showScriptName' => false` into your components urlManager array in /protected/config/main.php file:

```
// application components
'components'=>array(
    ...
    'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'showScriptName'=>false,
        'rules'=>array(
            ...
        ),
        ...
    ),
...
),
```

That would make the route for your contant page `mysite.com/site/contact`. In order to remove the `/site` you'd need to edit the rules array, something like this may work;

```
// application components
'components'=>array(
    ...
    'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'showScriptName'=>false,
        'rules'=>array(
            ...
            '<action:\w+>.php'=>'site/<action>',
            ...
        ),
        ...
    ),
...
),
```

This would mean the url `mysite.com/contact.php` will render the site/contact route.

**Edit**

In answer to your question 'no i want it to render mysite.com/one, where one is a string id':

You've got to be careful with such short url rules, as broad rules like that will be picked up by other paths and reroute the user when you don't want them to be redirected. However, to redirect `mysite/one` to `mysite/mycontroller/myaction?id=one` you could use `'<id:\w+>'=>'mycontroller/myaction'`

**But**, as I said, be careful, this will reroute *everything* with a one word path. for example take this scenario:

- You have a controller named `user`
- You want to navigate to the `index` action of the `user` controller (route `user/index`)
- You navigate to `mysite.com/user` (which would normally render `mysite.com/user/index`)

This would now instead redirect the user to `mysite/mycontroller/myaction?id=user`

Comment: thank you, but about a url like: mysite.com/controller/action?id=one , how to change it to mysite.com/action

Comment: `mysite.com/contact.php?id=1` should render `mysite.com/site/contact/id/1`, is this not what you mean?

Comment: no i want it to render mysite.com/one, where one is a string id